# JSON stringify sporadically replaces separator with closing square bracket

Tags: node.js, arrays, json

I am running a node.js script that culls through a directory and extracts any regex matches it finds, then pushes them onto an array. Once the query has run, I am stringifying the array into a standalone JSON file for safekeeping until it's needed.

I'm running into sporadic errors where the array in the JSON file is malformed and causes an error when I try to parse it out later on. It is sporadic, and I cannot determine a pattern, but every time (so far) the character that is causing the error is a closing square bracket - just like the one between the 2nd and 3rd elements below:

`["first string","second string"]"third string"]`

It's almost as if my `array.push()` is just adding another element onto the end of the existing array, and "forgetting" to change the closing square bracket to a comma...

I have searched, but cannot find references to a known error that would cause this. Has anyone seen this before?

Environment:
Node.js v19.0.0 | Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS | Intel i7 processor

Here's my code for generating the JSON files:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const devPath = '/home/user/directory';
const activeReminder = [];

function buildArray() {
  let getFiles = fs.readdirSync(devPath);
  getFiles.forEach(file => {
    splitMD(file);
  });
}

function splitMD(file) {
  if (path.extname(file) == ".md" & file != {}) {
    let data = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
    const line = data.split(/\r?\n/);
     const match = line.find(element => {
        extractions(element, file);
    });
  }
};

function extractions(element, file) {
  if (element.includes("- [ ] reminder: ")) { //the - [ ] is markdown for Obsidian
    const datedReminder = "- [ ] [["+file+"]]" + element.split('- [ ] reminder:')[1]
    activeReminder.push(datedReminder);
    buildReminderJSON();
  } 
}

function buildCcioJSON() {
  const reminderJSON = JSON.stringify(activeReminder);
  fs.writeFile("reminder.json", reminderJSON, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error while writing CCIO JSON:");
      return console.log(err);
    }
  })
}

buildArray();

module.exports = { buildArray };
```

Comment: Can't tell what's the problem without the code generating the JSON file.

Comment: @xehpuk I just added my JSON-generating code to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's causing the anomaly described above, but I created a script to correct it as a workaround until I can figure out a root cause. I'm running it as a crontab a few minutes after the crontab that creates the original array.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const devPath = '/home/user/directory'

function cleanup() {
    let getFiles = fs.readdirSync(devPath);
    getFiles.forEach(file => {
        splitJSON(file);
    });
  }
  
function splitJSON(file) {
  if (path.extname(file) == ".json" & file != {}) {
    let data = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
    const line = data.split(/\r?\n/);
     const match = line.find(element => {
        jsonCheck(element, file);
    });
  }
};

function jsonCheck(element, file) {
  if (element.includes("\"]\"")) {
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
        var result = data.replace(/\"\]\"/g, '","');
        fs.writeFile(file, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
           if (err) return console.log(err);
        });
      });
  }
}
cleanup();
module.exports = { cleanup };
```